# How to save UIAlertView text field value to .plist file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, plist, uialertview

i have alert window with text field and 2 buttons, i need to save text added in my text field to .plist file, how can i do these?

*.h file*

```
NSMutableDictionary *cameras;
```

*my alert code*

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex == [alertView firstOtherButtonIndex])
    {
        NSString *plistPath = [DOCUMENTS stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Cameras.plist"];
        NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:cameras format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:nil];
        if(plistData)
            [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: What part of this do you need help with? 1) Getting the text from the alert? 2) Creating the data to write? 3) Writing the plist file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take `text` from text field. Create one `NSDictionary`, and write to File.

```
UITextField *textfield = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
NSString *value =   [textfield text];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:value forKeys:@"key"];
[dictionary writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Comment: why stringValue and not text ? stringValue is not a property of UITextField